# "Large" else if tree in bash

Tags: bash, shell, if-statement, sh

```
if [ "$1" == "on" ]; then

        echo "Maintenance going on"
        echo "<maintenance/>" > $MFILE

else if [ "$1" == "off" ]; then

        echo "Maintenance going off"
        rm $MFILE

else if [ "$1" == "status" ]; then

        if [ -f $MFILE ]; then
                echo "Maintenance is ON"
        else
                echo "Maintenance is OFF"
        fi

else

        echo "ERROR: Unknown command $1"
        exit 1

fi
```

If I try to run this script I get an "unexpected end of file" error. I suspect it's because something is wrong in the if/else/else if, but I find it surprisingly hard to Google an example of how the syntax is supposed to be. Does anyone here know?

Comment: Shouldn't you be using `elif` instead of `else if`?

Comment: Errors belong on stderr, not stdout.  echo "ERROR ..." >&2

Answer (score 6):

you should use "elif", not "else if"

text from http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_07_02.html

> This is the full form of the if statement:
>
> if TEST-COMMANDS; then
>
> CONSEQUENT-COMMANDS;
>
> elif MORE-TEST-COMMANDS; then
>
> MORE-CONSEQUENT-COMMANDS;
>
> else ALTERNATE-CONSEQUENT-COMMANDS;
>
> fi
>
> The TEST-COMMANDS list is executed, and if its return status is zero,
>   the CONSEQUENT-COMMANDS list is executed. If TEST-COMMANDS returns a
>   non-zero status, each elif list is executed in turn, and if its exit
>   status is zero, the corresponding MORE-CONSEQUENT-COMMANDS is executed
>   and the command completes. If else is followed by an
>   ALTERNATE-CONSEQUENT-COMMANDS list, and the final command in the final
>   if or elif clause has a non-zero exit status, then
>   ALTERNATE-CONSEQUENT-COMMANDS is executed. The return status is the
>   exit status of the last command executed, or zero if no condition
>   tested true.

Comment: That's what I mean by hard to find an example. http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Bash-Prog-Intro-HOWTO-6.html says `else if`

Answer (score 6):

Slightly off-topic, but wouldn't the following be more readable:

```
case $1 in
on)
        echo "Maintenance going on"
        echo "<maintenance/>" > $MFILE
        ;;

off)

        echo "Maintenance going off"
        rm $MFILE
        ;;

status)

        if [ -f $MFILE ]; then
                echo "Maintenance is ON"
        else
                echo "Maintenance is OFF"
        fi
        ;;

*)    
        echo "ERROR: Unknown command $1"
        exit 1
        ;;

esac
```

Answer (score 3):

Option of `elif` has already been [posted by Kent](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9599207/925381) & an excellent alternative has been [posted by beny23](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9599356/925381), I hope this can provide some info. The reason you are getting the error `unexpected end of file` is because the `if`s have not been closed properly. (I am not sure if this is what Kaz is trying to say in the answer so I am adding this reponse) The way bash is seeing your script is
`if`..
`else`
  .. `if`
  .. `else`
  ..  .. `if`
, thus there are 2 missing `fi`.

```
if [ "$1" == "on" ]; then #if 1

        echo "Maintenance going on"
        echo "<maintenance/>" > $MFILE

else 
    if [ "$1" == "off" ]; then #if 2

        echo "Maintenance going off"
        rm $MFILE

    else 
        if [ "$1" == "status" ]; then #if 3

            if [ -f $MFILE ]; then #if 4
                echo "Maintenance is ON"
            else
                echo "Maintenance is OFF"
            fi #for if 4                                                                                                                                      
        else
            echo "ERROR: Unknown command $1"
            exit 1

        fi #for if 3
    fi #for if 2
fi #for if 1
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

Real sources of info, rather than relying on random web tutorials.

GNU bash info manual:

```
$ info bash
```

Man page:

```
$ man bash
```

The Single Unix Specification [Shell Grammar]: http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/xcu_chap02.html#tag_02_10

```
[... scrolling down ...]
/* The following are the reserved words. */

%token  If    Then    Else    Elif    Fi    Do    Done
/*      'if'  'then'  'else'  'elif'  'fi'  'do'  'done'   */

[...]
if_clause        : If compound_list Then compound_list else_part Fi
                 | If compound_list Then compound_list           Fi
                 ;
else_part        : Elif compound_list Then else_part
                 | Else compound_list
                 ;
```

Comment: These days, first hits in Google are generally not "random". The fact that StackOverflow questions are often among them is one of the driving forces of the site. But thanks for the info.

Comment: These days, first hits in Google are driven by keyword-stuffing search engine optimizers. Indeed, hardly random. :)